# AR vuforia integration with xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have two projects. One is native iOS app (UIKIT) and the other is AR Vuforia project which was made by Unity3D.

I can export AR project into XCODE project, but I am wondering how to link them together.

For example, I have a button on native iOS app. I want to trigger AR project when button is pressed and it can go back to native iOS app as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to have one app launch another (and vice-versa)?

If that is the case, then you just need to learn about Apple's URL scheme, which is described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html

It is really quite easy to use. You'll need to edit the PList for each app to give them a custom URL, which you can then invoke via the openURL method:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL: